# Different edge widths when saving networkx graph as pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

**Problem:** I would like to save a networkx plot in vectorised format (e.g. as pdf), but this does not preserve the expected edge widths.

**Example**: Consider the following snippet:

```
import networkx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Define graph
G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        weight = 1
        if i != j:
            if np.random.rand() < 0.7:
                weight = 0.01
            else:
                weight = 0.5*np.random.rand()
        G.add_edge('A{}'.format(i), 'B{}'.format(j), weight=weight)

# Plot graph
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
left_nodes, right_nodes = nx.bipartite.sets(G)
pos = dict()
pos.update((n, (1, i)) for i, n in enumerate(left_nodes))
pos.update((n, (2, i)) for i, n in enumerate(right_nodes))
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u, v in G.edges()]
color_map = ['lightblue' if n.startswith('A') else 'orange' for n in G]
nx.draw(G, 
        pos=pos,
        width=weights,
        node_color=color_map,
        node_size=1000,
        with_labels = True)
plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight');
```

This saves the following image as `test.png`:

[image]

In contrast, when I use a scalable vector format (e.g. save the image as `test.pdf`), the output is:

[image]

which does not preserve the expected edge widths. How can I save the plot in vector format such that it looks like the .png image?

Comment: You definitely have the thicker lines remaining thicker.  This looks to me like somehow there is a minimum thickness in the pdf image.  What happens if you zoom in on the original pdf?

Comment: Exactly - thicker lines remain thicker. Though the proportions are not visually kept. When I zoom in, thick lines become thicker and thin lines become thinner. Is there any workaround to make the two plots look the same at this level of magnification and have high resolution at the same time?

Comment: To me this sounds like the pdf viewer has limitations on how it displays really thin lines.  So the pdf file probably has the correct width in it, but the viewer doesn't show it that way.  I don't know anything about the details of how they work.

Comment: did you find a solution? i am experiencing the same issue

Comment: No, unfortunately... I ended up saving the image in .png format